# Hierarchical query Oracle and numeration with point (1 1.1 1.1.1 1.1.2 1.2 1.3 1.3.1 1.3.2 1.3.3 ....)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Hierarchical data.

```
select lpad(' ', 4*(level-1))||NAME 
from from_sql 
where where_sql 
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id 
START WITH parent_id is null
```

- work, all right.

out:

```
la1
    la2
    la3
        la4
    la5
        la6
        la7
la8
    la9
```

i need:

```
1    la1
1.1        la2
1.2        la3
1.2.1            la4
1.3        la5
1.3.1            la6
1.3.2            la7
2    la8
2.1        la9
```

how to do numeration with point?

Comment: seems like you could use a LAG function and a PLSQL function to take the current level and construct this value for each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(r, '.'), name
FROM
  (SELECT rank() over (partition BY parent_id
                    ORDER BY id) r,
                id,
                name,
                parent_id
  FROM from_sql 
 WHERE where_sql) t
   CONNECT BY
   PRIOR id = parent_id START WITH parent_id IS NULL
```

[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) is a fiddle

Comment: Thank you! fiddle - is great! Thank, too

Comment: +1 not for the answer per se but for introducing me to SQLfiddle ;)